# FB not returning email in some devices(android chrome combination)

Tags: android, facebook, email, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbsdk

FBsdk not returning email id for devices.same code working fine for all. chrome browser not returning email in Andriod devices. I have looked into many question but i dint found any solutions. im using 3.0 version.

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  loginFB();
} else {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
}}function checkLoginState() {
FB.login(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
},{scope: 'public_profile,email'}); }window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '1817426178332917',
  cookie     : true,
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v3.0'
})  }; (function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));  function loginFB() {
var o, e = document.URL;
y = e.substring(0, e.lastIndexOf("/")), 
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email,picture,first_name,last_name,birthday'},function(e) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + e.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + e.name + '!';
    user_email = e.email, alert("Successfulsssssssss login for: " +JSON.stringify(e)),console.log("Successfulsssssssss login for: " + e.name);
    var n = "isFBLogin=connected&fbEmail=" + user_email + "&fbNextAction=myAccount";
    o = "https:" == window.location.protocol ? "/eCommerceFacebookLoginSec?" : "/eCommerceFacebookLogin?", jQuery.getJSON(o + n, function(o) {
        window.location.replace(y + "/main")
    })
});  }
```

Comment: Does the user correctly get asked for the permission in the login dialog on those devices? After they granted it, does the permission actually show when you debug the access token? Did you test this with the same user accounts?

Comment: yes, I have tested it,it happening for same user

Comment: Was that supposed to be the answer to all three questions?

Comment: Yep thank you @CBroe